# Change Image with trigger in xaml based on boolean

Tags: xaml, xamarin, triggers

Hey I am trying to show different pictures based on boolean values with triggers, I have one image a simple where it shows the green one when it is true, that works but wiht the triggers, I get an empty unhandled exception.
What am I missing?
Thanks

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Content}" FontSize="26"></Label>
                            <Image Source="green.png"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit" IsVisible="{Binding Done}"></Image>
                            <Image>
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Done}" Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="red.png"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Done}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="green.png"></Setter>

                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>

                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: As my knowledge, your code should work fine. If possible, provide in which line the exception is thrown? or any stack trace details available?

Comment: I tried to run it now, but it shows an error that it wants a <DataTemplate DataType="TypeName"> in the datatype, but what does it want there?

Comment: ok managd to get the exception again http://imgur.com/a/Rl8PK

Comment: DataType in the DataTemplate is nothing but the DataContext you set to the DataTemplate. You can directly set the DataContext(say like any collection or something like that) to the DataType property.